# How a saas application coding is different from our traditional web applications?

Tags: saas

How a saas application coding is different from our traditional web applications? Please share some link where I can find some helpful tutorials. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

The main differences between the code of SaaS applications and traditional applications is the concurrency control and the resources consumption.

The concurrency control is necessary when you have multiple users accessing the same resources, so things like thread safety are crucial to this kind of application.

About the resources consumption, the efficiency of SaaS applications are much more important than traditional applications, because the hosting costs of SaaS are (normally) paid by the company who own the app, and impact directly on the company finance. Plus, all the resources used are multiplied by the number of users.

Other main concern that should be considered when programming SaaS applications is about the data separation: a user should never, ever, see data of another users registered in the application (there are exceptions, of course). This have extra weight when talking about SaaS applications in areas like finance and fiscal management, etc.

If you have more questions or want me to expand the answer in some specific direction, please let me know in the comments section.